# Put an equation next to an image next to an equation tag

Tags: graphics, amsmath, tabularx, tags

I am not sure I express my question correctly, but my objective is to reproduce this kind of presentation.
[image: CSA mode a]

And add an equation tag to the right of the image.

I am somewhat able to reproduce the equation and the image with this code.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,letterpaper, oneside, article]{memoir}

     \usepackage{amsmath}
     \usepackage{tabularx}
     \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{6 cm} X}
     $\displaystyle n_u = f_1 d_f t_1 \text{(N)}$
     &
     \includegraphics[width=8 cm]{./img/mode_a.jpg}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

But how could I add the equation number tag to the right of the image?

Comment: Remove the `pdftex` option from the `\documentclass` line and from `\usepackage{graphicx}`. It does nothing and makes the document not portable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a tabular for that.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,letterpaper, oneside, article]{memoir}

     \usepackage{amsmath}
     \usepackage{tabularx}
     \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 n_u &= f_1 d_f t_1 \text{(N)}
     &
     \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=8 cm]{./img/mode_a.jpg}}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** Since I was saying that it might look better with Ti*k*Z, I think I need to proof that.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper, oneside, article]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 n_u &= f_1 d_f t_1 \text{(N)}
     &
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,font=\sffamily,font=\footnotesize,baseline=(c.base),
murmel/.style={rectangle,thick,ultra thick, minimum width=2cm,minimum
height=0.5cm, draw,inner sep=0pt,align=left,text width=1.9cm,
append after command={% courtesy of Alenanno ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287967/drawing-thin-line-around-a-multipart-tikz-shape#comment696552_287972
\pgfextra{\draw (\tikzlastnode.north) -- (\tikzlastnode.south);}}}]
      \node[murmel] (l1) at (0,0)  {2};
      \draw[-stealth,line width=1mm]  (l1.west)-- ++ (-1,0);
      \node[murmel,above=0cm of l1,xshift=0.5cm] (l2) {1};
      \draw[-stealth,line width=1mm]  (l2.east)-- ++ (1,0);
      \node[murmel] (c) at (6.5,0.25)  {1};
      \draw[-stealth,line width=1mm]  (c.east)-- ++ (1,0);
      \node[murmel,above=0cm of c,xshift=-0.5cm] (r1)  {1};
      \node[murmel,below=0cm of c,xshift=-0.5cm] (r2)  {2};
      \draw[-stealth,line width=1mm]  (r1.west) -- ++(-1,0);
      \draw[-stealth,line width=1mm]  (r2.west) -- ++(-1,0);
      \draw[line width=1.8mm] ($(l2.north)+(0,0.1)$)--($(l2.south)+(0,-0.85)$);
      \draw[line width=1.8mm] ($(c.north)+(0,0.85)$)--($(c.south)-(0,0.85)$);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. To reduce code clutter, though, I'd omit the two mentions of the option `pdftex`, and I wouldn't load the `tabularx` package.

Comment: @Mico Yes, this is true, but I always try to accommodate the OP's inputs/wishes as far as possible. Personally, I would also draw the pic with Ti*k*Z such that the fonts are the same as in the ambient text and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I am currently learning to add images which include text that is latex generated.  Trying through `svg` and others, but I am not there yet.

Comment: @SimonBoucher Even though one is a bit overwhelmed when trying this for the first time, I'd like to argue that on the long run it pays off. So I added a Ti*k*Z version of your graphics.

Comment: @marmot Thank you, but considering the numerous graphic I would have to do, wouldn't be better to just export them from a vector graphic file, like .svg (which is an other game to make work) or  .eps which is manage natively? And for your example, to lighten the document, is there a way to call that TikZ graphic form else where?

Comment: @SimonBoucher There is inkscape, which has a plug-in (which I never could make work, but everyone else does) that allows you to export the graphics to Ti*k*Z. What I like about Ti*k*Z (and pstricks and asymptote the like) is that you can make global changes in your TeX document and you do not have to adjust each file separately. This is also helpful when you work in collaborations.

Comment: @marmot I tried the inkscape 2tizk plug-in, it works, I get a tizk file, but... not great for use at this point in learning.

Comment: @SimonBoucher Impressive! I never managed to get it installed. Note that one year ago I hardly knew that Ti*k*Z exists. Usually the learning curve is quite steep. Of course, certain limitations of LaTeX are a bit unfortunate, but overall it's great, and in many areas of science the only reasonable choice anyway.

Comment: i'd be tempted to add just a bit more space between equation and graphic.  (totally subjective preference.)

Answer (score 6):

If you want an equation with a tag (number), use an `equation`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = a x^2 + b x + c \qquad
  \includegraphics[height = 40pt, valign = c]{example-image}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Since graphics are typically set on the baseline, you can align them vertically with the help of [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox). Using the `export` package option, you can add `valign = c` to achieve a `c`entred `v`ertical `align`ment when placing your graphic.

If you want multiple (stacked) equations, use an `align` (or something similar).