# Tikz: Showing all node names (for debugging)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging

Is there an easy way to show the name of all nodes, say, in a scope? *Without* having to assign explicit styles to the nodes? (Context: complex figure, broken down in lots of subcommands, not feasible to change all of it).

My idea was something like this, but that ends in endless recursion:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[debugstyle/.style={
    append after command={% courtesy of Alenanno ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287967/drawing-thin-line-around-a-multipart-tikz-shape#comment696552_287972
      \pgfextra{\node [right] at (\tikzlastnode.mid east) {\tikzlastnode};}
      },
    }]

  % this works, but not what I want: 
  \node[debugstyle] (hello) at (0,0) {Hello world}; 

  % this fails, apparently endless recursion: 
  \begin{scope}[every node/.append style=debugstyle]
     \node (hello) at (0,0) {Hello world}; 
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your added node is itself a node and so picks up the `every node` style which adds another node that again adds a node which adds a node and ...

The trick is to disable the code that adds a node once the first stage has been achieved.  There are a variety of ways of doing this, but the basic idea will be the same: within the code that `debugstyle` invokes, we have to disable `debugstyle`.  A simple way to do that is with `debugstyle/.style={}`.  The grouping ensures that this only affects the inserted nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611853/86}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  debugstyle/.style={
    append after command={% courtesy of Alenanno ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287967/drawing-thin-line-around-a-multipart-tikz-shape#comment696552_287972
      \pgfextra{
        \tikzset{debugstyle/.style={}}
        \node [right] at (\tikzlastnode.mid east) {\tikzlastnode};
      }
    },
  },
]

  % this works, but not what I want: 
  \node[debugstyle] (hello1) at (0,0) {Hello world}; 

  % this fails, apparently endless recursion: 
  \begin{scope}[every node/.append style=debugstyle]
     \node (hello2) at (0,-2) {Hello world}; 
     \node (hello3) at (0,-3) {Hello world}; 
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Labelled nodes]

(I'd probably add some styling to the node names to make it clear that they are node names, and perhaps the `overlay` key so that they don't change positioning on the page.)

Comment: Ah, clever! Had not thought of aborting the recursion via grouping. Thanks!

Comment: @HolgerKarl It's something I learnt by the hard way.  Glad I could help.